# Webservice data localization

Tags: java, android, web-services, localization, runtime

I did localization in static data in application side but I also want to do localization in dynamic data that came from web service?
Can I do localization in web service data in Android side.
If Yes please let me know How?

Comment: You can do better approach for localization get data in both languages from web services instead of doing from your side.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I am also thinking about that but is there any other way to do this without getting all language data from backend ?

Comment: nope because i recently do this with 2 types of locales. also we cannot change locale string to different side from application level. so it's batter to use it from back-end.

Comment: Thank you again for your quick reply but as per my requirement it's needed from app side if it not possible from app then I will think and change back-end accordingly . Thanks Again